# How to print UTF-8 characters from WSGI 2.0.13 and core python 3.4 application

Tags: python, utf-8, uwsgi

I am new to python programming and I am using uwsgi 2.0.13.1 and python 3.4.4
Following is the code which is working perfectly fine for me:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    return [b"<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"]
```

Now, I want to return UTF-8 characters. So, I changed code as following and added some characters like 'অ उ ष'

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    abc = "<h1 style='color:blue'>অ उ षँHello There!</h1>"
    return [abc]
```

Now code is running properly but its not printing anything in browser screen.

If we change this line

```
return [abc]
```

to

```
return [abc.encode()]
```

**Then it's printing some other characters instead of 'অ उ ष'.
Can someone help me out what's going wrong here?**

Following are my wsgi.ini file configurations:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /var/www/html/python_test/
wsgi-file = /var/www/html/python_test/test.py
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
encoding = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Are you sure your text editor, the one you use to put the characters into the python code, writes the python file in utf8?

Comment: Yes, I checked it properly. It is writing python file in utf8

Comment: I copy-pasted your code to test it, and it gives the expected result in my browser. (the version with `.encode()` in it)

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html;')])
```

instead of

```
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
```

Now it worked for me.

Comment: Glad you fixed your issue. Out of curiosity, what browser are you using to test?